# Read class decorator information in typescript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a class decorated with attributes.

I would like to read the attributes in the constructor ( or other method ).

I have tried using Reflect and all possible methods on that class but I only get undefined

The class looks like this

```
@inject(Element)
@bindable('color')
export class Messagebarhost {

public element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(element) {
  console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", this));
  // prints undefined
  // somehow I want to read the value 'color'
  }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the bundled js file where the decorators are created. Below line will print the correct value if I enter it in the debugger

```
r.__metadata__.undefined["aurelia:resource"].properties[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't put the decorator on the class but rather on a field as shown below:

```
@inject(Element)
export class Messagebarhost {

  public element: HTMLElement;
  @bindable color;


  constructor(element) {
     // this.color is not bound here yet.
  }

  attached () {
    // You need to wait till the attached or the bind function is
    // called to get the correct value in this.color.
  }
}
```